# Несколько init-expression в for

Tags: c++, циклы

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Search(string* Array, int Size, string* Words) {
    ifstream *Read = new ifstream[Size];

    for (int I = 0; I < Size; I++) {
        Read[I].open(Array[I]);
        if (!Read[I]) {
            cout << "Файл с именем: " << Array[I] << "не может быть открыт \n";
        }
        // В следующей строке в возникает ошибка I должно иметь константное значение
        //Ошибки нет, если "string Value" вынести из цикла
        //Почему возникает ошибка ?
        for (string Value, Read[I] >> Value; !Read[I].eof(); Read[I] >> Value) {
            // Что-то делающий код
        }

    }

    for (int I = 0; I < Size; I++) {
        Read[I].close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Такое использование `eof()` приедет к неправильной работе кода, например, если последняя строка файла не заканчивается на `\n`. В С/С++ программах не должно быть использования `eof()`, за исключением рада узких случаев.

Comment: может быть, вам подойдет что-то такое: ```for (string Value; Read[I] >> Value;)```?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В синтаксисе `for`

*for ( init-statement condition<sub>opt</sub> ; expression<sub>opt</sub> ) statement*

первая часть - *init-statement* - является либо *выражением*, либо *объявлением*.

Вы изначально использовали синтаксис `string Value, [...]`, который явно говорит, что в вашем случае в качестве *init-statement* вы хотите использовать именно *объявление*, а не *выражение*. Однако дальнейший синтаксис `[...], Read[I] >> Value` не является корректным синтаксисом объявления. Отсюда и ошибка.

(Странно, что вы в своем вопросе называете эту часть синтаксиса `for` "init-expression", хотя в вашем же примере это никакой не expression.)

Выбирайте: либо *выражение*, либо *объявление*. Перемешать выражение с объявлением вот так вот в лоб, как у вас, не получится.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for (string Value, Read[I] >> Value; !Read[I].eof(); Read[I] >> Value) {
> ```

1. Да, так нельзя, потому что `Read[I] >> Value` - это не объявление переменной.
2. Можно так:

   ```
   for (string Value; Read[I] >> Value, !Read[I].eof(); ) {
   ```
3. В коде баг и нужно так:

   ```
   for (string Value; Read[I] >> Value; ) {
   ```

Comment: Посоветуете актуальную литературу/сайт по изучению C++ ? Читал Alex Allain "Jumping into C++" по-нашему "От ламера до программера", затем читал MSDN справочник по C++, но все же не все понял